# if/else in controller and view Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app that I am integrating Bitcoin into using BlockIo API. When a user wants to make a payment, a new Bitcoin address is created for them and saved on the db, and after they make a payment the the amount is also saved, and that amount is retrieved from the API. I need assistance with the syntax or proper way to get the conditional statement working.

To generate and save a new Bitcoin address in the controller the code is:

```
@new_address = BlockIo.get_new_address
Payment.create( btc: @new_address['data']['address'] )
```

I want to create a conditional statement that will display the already generated bitcoin address if the amount (`amount:`) of the last Payment (`Payment.last`) is `<= '0.00000000' || == nil`, else generate a new address.

The attributes for the Payment model/controller are `bitcoin:string` and `amount:string`

**Update:** The below code works, but first displays @last_address and then upon refresh displays the newly generated address in the view.

```
def create_address
  @last_address = Payment.last.bitcoin
  @last_amount = Payment.last.amount

  if @last_amount == '0.00000000' || @last_amount == nil
    @last_address
  else
    @new_address = BlockIo.get_new_address
    Payment.create( btc: @new_address['data']['address'] )
  end
end
```

But the above code is not working, as it does not generate a new address when I update last Payments' amount to a bigger amount via console.

**Please advise on how I can better the below code to get the desired result:**

```
Send your Bitcoins to:

<% if @last_address %>
  <strong><%= @last_address %></strong><br>
  <%= image_tag src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=#{@last_address}" %>
<% else %>
  <strong><%= @new_address['data']['address'] %></strong><br>
  <%= image_tag src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=#{@new_address["data"]["address"]}" %>
<% end %>
```

**Update:** Please advise if my view code is correct, as I still first see the "old" @last_address and need to refresh to see the actual new generated @last_address.

Comment: Why `('0.00000000').to_i` ? This is equivalent to `0`, so why not just `@last_amount.to_i == 0` ? Will you ever have a negative amount? If not you don't need the `<=`, just equality.

Comment: Hi, the JSON data that I get have a value called available_balance which is 0.00000000 if no payment has been made to an address, and that is how the number is saved in the database as a string, the code does seem to work a bit better if I do     if @last_amount == '0.00000000'

Comment: How are you updating the last payment? You would have to update the last payment then go back to the view that is being served with the create address action.

Comment: The user would click and be directed to a view that automatically generates and saves that address, I am looking at also displaying the address on the same view, this is what I have in my routes    match '/save_btc' => 'payments#create_address', via: [:get, :post] and to update the amount I have
      match '/deposits' => 'payments#balance', via: [:get, :patch]

Comment: `@last_address` will always be set in your logic...

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it to work the way I want although it still feels a bit hacky as I have made sure that the page refreshes after the new address is saved, thus only displaying the latest saved address.

```
def create_address
  @last_address = Payment.last.bitcoin
  @last_amount = Payment.last.amount

  if @last_amount == '0.00000000' || @last_amount == nil
    @last_address
  else
    @new_address = BlockIo.get_new_address
    Payment.create( btc: @new_address['data']['address'] )
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to '/save_btc'}
    end
  end
end
```